# Make numpy.random generated numbers consistent across different functions

Tags: python, numpy, random

Assume you have two functions like these:

```
import numpy as np


def function_1(seed):

    res = []
    np.random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(10):
        res.append(np.random.rand())

    return res


def function_2(seed):

    res = []
    np.random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(10):
        a = np.random.rand()  # necessary!
        res.append(np.random.rand())

    return res
```

They are basically the same, just that in `function_2` you are required to generate an additional random number for each run of the for-loop.

Now,

```
x = function_1(1)
y = function_2(1)
x == y
>>> False
```

However, you need to make sure that the returned `res` is identical for both functions. Is there a better way than changing `function_1` to the following?

```
def function_3(seed):

    res = []
    np.random.seed(seed)
    for i in range(10):
        np.random.rand()
        res.append(np.random.rand())

    return res
```

Then,

```
z = function_3(1)
y == z
>>> True
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: I misread your question.  The way you are doing it is just about the simplest way.  A cleaner way IMO is to replace `np.random.seed`, with `np.random.RandomState`

Comment: I agree. Generate two instances of np.random.RandomState and use one of them in append and the other one in additional random call.

Comment: You could save the state immediately before one call, pass that state out of the function, and reset with that state in the other function.  This approach is more generic and flexible, so that, for example, one function wouldn't need to know so much about the other one (eg, how many times it called random); it would work for multiple functions, involve fewer calls to `random`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. I will definitively have a look into the docs for `np.random.RandomState` and think about what solution is the best for my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dedicated RandomState for the sequence that must be identical:

```
def function_2(seed):

    res = []
    random1 = np.random.RandomState(seed)
    for i in range(10):
        a = np.random.rand() # uses global state, no explicit seed
        res.append(random1.rand())

    return res
```

By the way, you really should try `res = random1.rand(10)` to do it without the loop.  It will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with specifying the `random.rand` output. I just tried to come up with a structure that is kind of similar to my real problem and figured it was not a problem if the example here is inefficient as long as the problem is addressed.